# Can not consume TFS 2013 events. Events simply are not firing in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs

We have a Visual Studio 2010 addin which basically handles TFS operations. When someone checkins some files, it sends emails to corresponding people and makes some changes on some other local MSSQL database and similiar situations for check-out and merge.

It was working along with TFS2005 for a very long time but recently we have upgraded our tfs from 2005 to 2010 and then to 2013.

Now our addin does not work. Simply, `VersionControlServer`'s events are not firing. No matter how i tried to do, googled it i couldn't find any solution. We think TFS2013 handles those matters differently but this addin is essential for us to work and we don't want to rollback to TFS2005.

Here is my sample code;

```
public void invoke()
{
    // Get a reference to our Team Foundation Server.
    var tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(_tfsURL));

    // Get a reference to Version Control.
    var versionControl = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

    // Listen for the Source Control events.
    versionControl.Getting += new GettingEventHandler(versionControl_Getting);
    versionControl.BeforeCheckinPendingChange += new ProcessingChangeEventHandler(versionControl_BeforeCheckinPendingChange);
    versionControl.NewPendingChange += new PendingChangeEventHandler(versionControl_NewPendingChange);
}

private void versionControl_NewPendingChange(object sender, PendingChangeEventArgs e)
{
     //some logic here
}

private void versionControl_BeforeCheckinPendingChange(object sender, ProcessingChangeEventArgs e)
{
     //some logic here
}

private void versionControl_Getting(object sender, GettingEventArgs e)
{
     //some logic here
}
```

Any ideas which causes that problem?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**  I've found the solution. Instead of using the code block above, i've changed it like;

```
        //+     _applicationObject.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerExt")   {Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerExt} dynamic {Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerExt}
        var tfsExt = (TeamFoundationServerExt)_applicationObject.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerExt");

        //if ((tfsExt == null) || (tfsExt.ActiveProjectContext == null) || (tfsExt.ActiveProjectContext.DomainUri == null) || (tfsExt.ActiveProjectContext.ProjectUri == null)) { MessageBox.Show("Please Connect to TFS first and select a Team Project"); }
        //else { MessageBox.Show("Connected to:" + tfsExt.ActiveProjectContext.ProjectName); }

        var vsExt = _applicationObject.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt") as VersionControlExt;

        //vcs = vsExt.Explorer.Workspace.VersionControlServer;
        vcs = vsExt.SolutionWorkspace.VersionControlServer;

        vcs.OperationStarting += new OperationEventHandler(this.OperationHandler);
        vcs.UndonePendingChange += new PendingChangeEventHandler(this.UndoChange);
        vcs.Getting += new GettingEventHandler(this.GetHandler);
        vcs.NewPendingChange += new PendingChangeEventHandler(this.NewPendingChange);
        vcs.BeforeCheckinPendingChange += new ProcessingChangeEventHandler(this.BeforeCheckinPendingChange);
        vcs.CommitCheckin += new CommitCheckinEventHandler(this.CommitCheckin);
        vcs.Conflict += new ConflictEventHandler(this.Conflict);
        vcs.Merging += new MergeEventHandler(this.Merging);
        vcs.AfterWorkItemsUpdated += new AfterWorkItemsUpdatedEventHandler(this.AfterWorkItemsUpdated);
        vcs.BeforeWorkItemsUpdate += new BeforeWorkItemsUpdateEventHandler(this.BeforeWorkItemsUpdate);
        vcs.OperationFinished += new OperationEventHandler(this.OperationFinished);
        vcs.UpdatedWorkspace += new WorkspaceEventHandler(this.UpdatedWorkspace);
        vcs.WorkItemUpdated += new WorkItemUpdatedEventHandler(this.WorkItemUpdated);
```

and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerExt` has made the trick.
Thank you everyone for support.

Also Daniel has a description here; http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e1433eb6-6418-46ed-8e18-7a9878e416c1/visual-studio-addin-to-intercept-checkin-checkout-and-other-tfs-2010-version-control-events?forum=tfsversioncontrol

**UPDATE 2**
No matter how much i say "thank you" it's not enough for Carlos Quintero helps.
Thanks again my good man!

Comment: This looks correct.  I don't see the code that does a get, for instance, or creates new pending changes.  Are you sure you have the same `VersionControlServer` object? Can you post a more complete code sample?

Comment: Hello @EdwardThomson, there are no code for getting or creating new pending changes. User interaction should fire those events, for example if addin is enabled in the addins menu, when user tries to checks out some file; i need those events to fire and as a result some window forms should pop out for user to select dependent issue for editing. If you want to see more, i think i can post a little bit more code... Thank you by the way. PS: This source code was working perfectly with TFS2005.

Comment: And by the way, could .net framework be the cause of this problem? After tfs upgrade i've migrated solution projects to .net framework 4 too. And are there any log files or something in tfs folders which would display errors or anythin?

Comment: Added your solution as answer.

Comment: What is _applicationObject?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. Instead of using the code block above, i've changed it like;

```
//+     _applicationObject.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerExt")   {Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerExt} dynamic {Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerExt}
var tfsExt = (TeamFoundationServerExt)_applicationObject.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerExt");

//if ((tfsExt == null) || (tfsExt.ActiveProjectContext == null) || (tfsExt.ActiveProjectContext.DomainUri == null) || (tfsExt.ActiveProjectContext.ProjectUri == null)) { MessageBox.Show("Please Connect to TFS first and select a Team Project"); }
//else { MessageBox.Show("Connected to:" + tfsExt.ActiveProjectContext.ProjectName); }

var vsExt = _applicationObject.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt") as VersionControlExt;

//vcs = vsExt.Explorer.Workspace.VersionControlServer;
vcs = vsExt.SolutionWorkspace.VersionControlServer;

vcs.OperationStarting += new OperationEventHandler(this.OperationHandler);
vcs.UndonePendingChange += new PendingChangeEventHandler(this.UndoChange);
vcs.Getting += new GettingEventHandler(this.GetHandler);
vcs.NewPendingChange += new PendingChangeEventHandler(this.NewPendingChange);
vcs.BeforeCheckinPendingChange += new ProcessingChangeEventHandler(this.BeforeCheckinPendingChange);
vcs.CommitCheckin += new CommitCheckinEventHandler(this.CommitCheckin);
vcs.Conflict += new ConflictEventHandler(this.Conflict);
vcs.Merging += new MergeEventHandler(this.Merging);
vcs.AfterWorkItemsUpdated += new AfterWorkItemsUpdatedEventHandler(this.AfterWorkItemsUpdated);
vcs.BeforeWorkItemsUpdate += new BeforeWorkItemsUpdateEventHandler(this.BeforeWorkItemsUpdate);
vcs.OperationFinished += new OperationEventHandler(this.OperationFinished);
vcs.UpdatedWorkspace += new WorkspaceEventHandler(this.UpdatedWorkspace);
vcs.WorkItemUpdated += new WorkItemUpdatedEventHandler(this.WorkItemUpdated);
```

and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerExt` has made the trick.

Also [Daniel has a description here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e1433eb6-6418-46ed-8e18-7a9878e416c1/visual-studio-addin-to-intercept-checkin-checkout-and-other-tfs-2010-version-control-events?forum=tfsversioncontrol);